# Passing the input parameters dynamically in angular template

Tags: angular, components, wrapper

I have `more-options-menu` component in angular. It has few input params like- size, color, inline etc, any my angular selector looks like this-

```
<more-options-menu size="40" color="accent"></more-options-menu>
```

And the component looks like this-

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MIconRegistry } from '@once/ui';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'more-options-menu',
  template: '<my-icon size svgIcon color inline></my-icon>',
  inputs: ['color', 'svgIcon', 'size', 'inline']
})
export class MoreOptionsMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  size;
  svgIcon;
  color;
  inline;
  constructor(
    private IconRegistry: MIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    this.IconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/hello/135790/20/symbol-defs.svg?8ctxpf'
      )
    );

    this.IconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/hello/135790/24/symbol-defs.svg?8ctxpf'
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I want to make these parameters dynamically. I want whatever inputs are passed to more-options-menu to go directly to `my-icon` component. `more-options-menu` is a wrapper component for `my-icon`. I'm trying to see if I can just wrap the `my-icon` component so that I won't have to update `more-options-menu` every time I update `my-icon` component
 i.e. provide a fix so we won't have to update it (`more-options-menu`) thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass an entire object through and do something like the following:

First declare an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) and make the properties optional:

```
interface IValues{
    color?: string;
    svgIcon?: string;
    ...
}
```

Then in your component expect the input of that Interface type:

```
@Input('values') values: IValues;
```

This now allows you to pass an object of whatever you want through to your component - just make sure to null check all your values before using them:

```
<more-options-menu [values]='valuesIWantToPass'></more-options-menu>
```

Where `valuesIWantToPass == {color= 'abc'}`

---

**Edit:**

From the comments, just pass it right on through as an input straight into `my-icon`. i.e. identical `@Input('values') values: IValues;` on both your components and then `<my-icon [values]='valuesIWantToPass'></more-options-menu>`

See this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohua5z

Comment: Thank you @Zze How `<more-options-menu [values]='valuesIWantToPass`  `values` will be passed to  `my-icon` component. I don't want to change the code of `my-icon`. What do you suggest?

FYI- `more-options-menu` is a wrapper component for `my-icon`. I'm trying to see if I can just wrap the my-icon component so that we won't have to update more-options-menu every time I update my-icon component.

Comment: <my-icon has 4 different Inputs- size, color and two more. I can't customize my-icon. Not sure how it will work

Comment: I am understnading what you are saying, but the problem is I cann't update `my-icon` component which is `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohua5z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fother.component.ts` in your case. the file has 4 inputs  which I cann't change

Comment: @DineshRawat Ok, well you need to update your question to emphasis that because currently it says: *"so that we won't have to update"* i.e. provide a fix so we won't have to update it thereafter.

Comment: Edited the text in the question.